# AngularJS radio button groups with name attribute not initializing properly

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, radio-group

The radio buttons group doesn't seem to initialize property inside a `ng-repeat` block if we specify the `name` attribute to the group. It seems working for the last set of radio groups, but not for the rest. Also, it works fine if I remove the `name` attribute. Per [AngularJS documentation][1], the `name` attribute is not needed if we use it with `ngModel`. But it doesn't say we must not use it. And I need to specify a `name` attribute.

Please refer to the example below:

```js
var m = angular.module("MyApp", []);

m.controller("MyController", ["$scope", function($scope) {
  
  $scope.myArr = [{
    name: "Obj 1",
    status: "a"
  }, {
    name: "Obj 2",
    status: "b"
  }, {
    name: "Obj 3",
    status: "c"
  }];
}]);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #1D1F20;
}
 
.row {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.demo {
  background: green;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  min-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyController" class="demo">
    <div ng-repeat="eachItem in myArr" class="row">
        
        <span>{{eachItem.name}} => </span>
        
        <label> a
          <input name="status-$index" type="radio" ng-model="eachItem.status" value="a">
        </label>
        
        <label> b
          <input name="status-$index" type="radio" ng-model="eachItem.status" value="b">
        </label>
        
        <label> c
          <input name="status-$index" type="radio" ng-model="eachItem.status" value="c">
        </label>
        
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try <input name="status-{{ $index }}" type="radio" ng-model="eachItem.status" value="a">

Comment: Awesome. That worked. Thanks @Mickers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine except the place where you are setting the name attribute to input.

`$index` in template will be evaluated only if you enclose it inside curly brackets.
EX: `{{$index}}` else you will get $index in the name. You should use:

```
 <div ng-repeat="eachItem in myArr track by $index" class="row">
   <input name="status-{{$index}}" type="radio" ng-model="eachItem.status" value="a">...
 </div>
```